# Is multiple use of --exclude-from=FILE possible in rsync?

Tags: rsync

The manual does not specify (nor exclude for that matter) whether I can specify on the command line `--exclude-from=FILE` multiple times, like so:

```
rsync -av --exclude-from=FILE1 --exclude-from=FILE2 source destination
```

So is it possible to specify different exclude files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `--exclude-from` multiple times to specify different exclude files. And this can be helpful if you want to separate the different class of files into separate exclude files.

This is the **directory structure** and I have to remove the executable and the temp files generated.

```
root-dir/
├── dir1
│   ├── dir1-1
│   │   ├── a.out
│   │   └── file1.txt
│   └── dir1-2
│       ├── a.out
│       └── file2.txt
├── dir2
│   └── dir2-1
│       ├── a.out
│       ├── file3.txt
│       └── README.md
└── dir3
    ├── dir3-1
    │   └── a.exe
    ├── dir3-2
    │   ├── a.out
    │   ├── program1.cpp
    │   ├── program1.ii
    │   ├── program1.o
    │   └── program1.s
    └── dir3-3
        ├── a.out
        ├── program2.cpp
        ├── program2.ii
        ├── program2.o
        └── program2.s
```

Use the **command**

```
rsync --exclude-from exclude-exec --exclude-from exclude-temps -av SRC/ DEST/
```

**exclude-exec** contains

```
*.out
*.exe
```

**exclude-temps** contains

```
*.ii
*.o
*.s
```

The **directory structure** after the operation becomes,

```
root-dir/
├── dir1
│   ├── dir1-1
│   │   └── file1.txt
│   └── dir1-2
│       └── file2.txt
├── dir2
│   └── dir2-1
│       ├── file3.txt
│       └── README.md
└── dir3
    ├── dir3-1
    ├── dir3-2
    │   └── program1.cpp
    └── dir3-3
        └── program2.cpp
```

Comment: Confirmed. The question is of the type you can answer just by trying and reviewing the result; therefore I was surprised to see the answer is not from the asker. +1 for you who took the effort.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski getting an answer here will confirm that it will work across all distros but also helps me to understand the confusion in the man page and it's use of OR (which is wrong):  "Note also that the --filter, --include, and --exclude options take one rule/pattern each. To add multiple ones, you can repeat the options on the command-line, use the merge-file syntax of the --filter option, or the --include-from/--exclude-from options." The last "or" could mean you either need to use many ''excludes'' or ONE exclude file, but does not confirm multiple uses of --exclude-from.